# PEP 8 and Python decorators

Tags: python, decorator, pep8, python-decorators

I'm working on a project where I have a class with some 10ish decorators on it, where I'm using them to provide validation on some methods and attributes (if it's relevant, the validation is very general, and re-used elsewhere on other classes).  I've been advised by a friend who is a lot more of a PEP8 stickler than I am that this is bad form---however, I cannot [find a cite](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for [that](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/style/), or even good advice on what constitutes a good use of a decorator versus a bad or non-essential one.

My own introduction to using decorators came from Flask, where they provide routing information, and can be stacked a couple deep.  Could someone provide cited information on proper versus improper decorator usage, and better alternatives?

Comment: This is an intriguing question, but it might help to show a sample of what your code looks like

Comment: Wait, its ten decorators on top of one class??

Comment: Decorators are basically just functions applied with nice syntax. This is about app-design, not coding style, well outside the scope of PEP 8.

Comment: Basically, if a decorator makes often-repeated boilerplate code collapse into one line for the decorator, you are doing it right.

Comment: Your stack traces must look like hell

Comment: Hey all, thanks for your quick replies.  They're helpful, but I'm going to flesh this out with an example later (which I need to sanitize a little).

Answer (score 3):

What matters in Python is code readability. 10 or so decorators might be pretty hard to keep track of, while 2 o 3 are easier to read. You don't need a convention for every character you type: sometimes, you just have to go for what is easier to read

Answer (score 2):

As Martijn Pieters said in comments, decorators are just functions applied on the function defined below. To keep a script readable I would recommend to keep not more than 3 or 4 decorators. But the PEP8 doesn't give any advise about the number of decorators you should stack, because it isn't the goal of the PEP :)

If you have more than that, it's a **architecture/app-design problem**, not a coding style issue. You may need to redefine your architecture, espcially if you apply the same suite of decorators on every functions.

Answer (score 1):

I would say - purely as a matter of opinion and from a readability point that more than a couple of decorators is not a good idea - especially since the ordering can be critical.  You would be better of seeing if there are any base classes - possibly with decorators of their own that you can logically split your class into in an inheritance hierarchy.

If it is a sensible separation then the decorators will match what the classes are doing/contain, e.g. if you have a parameter class validation with a validation decorator and that inherits from a string_parameter class that has string validation, etc.,  You will end up with more understandable classes and decorators.

Note that you can also stack decorators - i.e. a decorator that decorates a decorator.

Comment: Should 'stacking' be read as a decorator that decorates _the result of_ a decorator?

Comment: @xtofl I would say that since a decorator can modify both the inputs and results of a function or method that a decorator "wraps" a method and that the decorator/wrapper can itself have decorator(s)/wrapper(s).